# Double Click event for each Chart Areas in MSChart C#

Tags: graph, mschart

The problem is I created Chart using MSChart with two ChartAreas. 
But, I want to handle the doubleClick events of these two seperate chartareas seperately.

But, I can't do that. Double Click event is only applicable for entire Chart not for individual chart area.

Please let me know if there is any other way.

Actually, i want make visiblility of other chart area to false when other chart area is double clicked.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub MSChart1_MouseClick....
 Dim result As HitTestResult = MSChart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
 Dim CurrentChartAreaName as String  
 If IsNothing(result.ChartArea) = False Then  
     CurrentChartAreaName = Result.ChartArea.ChartArea.Name
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Provided code might help, but in order to make it a good answer you should also describe/explain why/how exactly does your code solve the problem.